# How to redefine environment that has arguments?

Tags: environments, wrapfigure

To produce html and pdf files from the same set of sources I need to transform all wrapfigure environments (package wrapfig) to standard figure environments. One example is:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{i}{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{parabola}
\caption{La traiettoria bla bla.}
\label{fig:parabola}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Defining something like this (and not loading wrapfig package):

```
\newenvironment{wrapfigure}[3]{\begin{figure}[htb]\centering}{\end{figure}}
```

works but leaves an annoying ']i0pt' between image and caption.
Any idea (except manual editing of the resulting html...)
Thanks!

Comment: try: `\newenvironment{wrapfigure}[3][]{\begin{figure}[htb]\centering}{\end{figure}}` but I suppose that it has more optional arguments

Comment: You might also want to look at the `xparse` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) manual states that the syntax is:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[<number of narrow lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>}
    <figure>
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Note the two optional and two mandatory arguments.
You need to define a replacement which removes all of this possible arguments. This is possible by removing the first two with as environment arguments and then use a gobble macro to remove the other two:

```
\newcommand{\gobbleom}[2][]{}
\newenvironment{wrapfigure}[2][]
    {\begin{figure}[htb]\centering\gobbleom}
    {\end{figure}}
```

---

You could also use the `xparse` package to define an environment with two such optional arguments:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{wrapfigure}{omom}
      {\begin{figure}[htb]\centering}
      {\end{figure}}
```

Using `xparse` is very useful if you want to redefine very complicated macros or environments.
However, if you want to reduce the number of used packages I would go with the first method.